# Javascript count length specific string

Tags: javascript

i have a problem when **count** `length` with spesific **string**;

basically, i have a string that store at variable.

something like this :

```
var x = "<p class='test'>one</p>
         <p class='test'>two</p>
         <p class='test'>three</p>
         <p class='test'>four</p>";

var count = x.length // expected 4 as result
```

how to accompolished this thing?

thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to count the amount of elements in this string?

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish? what is the result you're getting?

Comment: There is a problem in the syntax: use alternatively single and double quotes for distinguing the quote inside and outside the string.

Comment: He wants to count p tags , I guess

Comment: if what @LPK says is right it should be an array, not a string

Comment: @Kalpesh Singh, exactly

Comment: is it possible for you to store in array, then it will be hell easy to count length. or you want in your way only?

Comment: @Kalpesh Singh, yup! is it possible?

Comment: I guess, you got answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `String.match(new RegExp()).length`

```
var x =  "<p class='test'>one</p>" + 
         "<p class='test'>two</p>" + 
         "<p class='test'>three</p>" +
         "<p class='test'>four</p>";

x.match(new RegExp("<p", "g") || []).length //4
//or count </p>
x.match(new RegExp("</p>", "g") || []).length //4
//or old 2009 answer
(x.split("<p").length - 1) //4
```

Comment: epic! this method works like a champ! thank you so much Medet! so much downvote anyway. LOL

Comment: @ChingChing because you didn't googled it, that's why people don't like this question

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the data as a string and strings don't care what the characters are, they just see it all. If you want to be able to store the strings that make up paragraph elements and know how many of those you've made, you need an array of strings, like this:

```js
    var x = [];
    x.push("<p class='test'>one</p>");
    x.push("<p class='test'>two</p>");
    x.push("<p class='test'>three</p>");
    x.push("<p class='test'>four</p>");
    

    alert(x.length); // 4

    x.push("<p class='test'>five</p>");

    alert(x.length); // 5
```

Comment: thanks Scott for answering, your method also working. but, you store it on array. i have a condition where this method not compatible. anyway, you are very nice! thanks Scott!

Comment: @ChingChing You answered Kalpesh in the comments above that an array would work for you.

Comment: sorry, i'm not really expert on english. so, deal with it LOL. thanks Scott

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create a div from your string and count the child elements.

```
var x = '<p class="test">one</p>'+
        '<p class="test">two</p>'+
        '<p class="test">three</p>'+
        '<p class="test">four</p>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = x;
var count = div.childNodes.length;

alert(count);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dttz64qn/

Comment: @ChingChing No problem. Hopefully you understand why these answers work and the difference between `string.length` and count of HTML elements.